# What features can I use during log in/out

Tags: c#, windows-xp

I know that this question is going to be painfully vague, but here it is any way.

I have made an small console application designed to be run on Windows XP Pro computers. It will be run at log in and log out. The command to run this program will be set via GPO and will include command line operators to control what data the program sends.

I have used a few built in C# classes to find out information about the computer, which is then sent of to a server as a web request.

I need to know which of the following will have issues on a restricted user account on a domain.

`Enviroment`
`ManagementObjectSearcher`
`ManagmentObjectCollection`
`System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter` <-- side note, this class dosent seem to accept be saying `using System.Diagnostics`
`ComputerInfo`
`WebRequest`

Comment: Just a side note, you should set up a Test Suite which tests this. :)

Comment: yer... I know exactly how to do that... (Did I get away with that?)... Didn't think so :( Know of any good guides for this, or shall I just trawl Google?